# add a field value from code

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm using Grocery CRUD with CodeIgniter, and I have this table :

```
annonce (id, name, id_user).
```

the `id_user` is a foreign key which references to another table `user(id,....).`

I don't want to add the `user_id` in an input when I add an entry in the annonce table, I have the `user_id` in the session, so I want when I add a new entry to specify the user id in the code.

how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden input.
Like this:

```
$crud->field_type('user_id', 'hidden', $_SESSION['user_id']);
```

Or use invisible for more security. You can look the sample here:
http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/field_type